# Multiplatform automation script for delphi

Tags: delphi, automation

I´m trying to build a automation script to build and deploy an app.

Windows and Android works flawlessly, but not for iOS. It builds ok, but dont deploy.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(696,5): error : Missing provisioning information. Mobile Provisioning Profile has not been specified for the "AppStore" platform configuration. [C:\Delphi\Projects\Tests\ShowMeTheMoney.dproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Delphi\Projects\Tests\ShowMeTheMoney.dproj" (Deploy target(s)) -- FAILED.

This is not a problem with paclient, certificates and so on. If i press Shift+Ctrl+Alt+F9 inside the ide it all goes ok.

I´ve tried to dig in C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin*.targets but i didnt find any clue.

Where do i set the correct profiles?

Thats what i have so far:

```
@REM //////////////////////////////////////////
@REM /////////    BUILD INDIVIDUAL   //////////
@REM //////////////////////////////////////////

@echo off
set root=C:\Delphi\Projects
set filepath=%~p1
set filename=%~n1
set logfile=%root%\.build\%filename%.log
rem set logfile=con 

call "%root%\.build\rsvars.bat"
call "%root%\.build\mobile_vars.bat"

cd %filepath%

%root%\.build\GetNextBuildNumber %filename% %filepath%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  goto :fail
)

%root%\.build\ChangeVersion %1 "%filepath%%filename%_VersionInfo.txt"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  goto :fail
)

if %PLATFORM%==Win32 (
  set BTYPE=Normal
) ELSE (
  set BTYPE=AppStore
)

msbuild /t:Build /p:Config=Release /p:BT_BuildType=%BTYPE% %filename%.dproj /toolsversion:4.0 > %logfile%
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  goto :fail
) 

if %PLATFORM% NEQ Win32 (
  msbuild /t:Deploy /p:Config=Release /p:platform=%PLATFORM%   %filename%.dproj > %logfile%
)

if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  goto :fail
) 

goto :success

:fail
if exist %logfile% (
  start %logfile%
) else (
  pause
)  
exit /b

:success
if exist %logfile% (
  del %logfile%
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Did you look at https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Building_a_Project_Using_an_MSBuild_Command ?

Comment: Yes i did, no mention there on how to solve my issue. Thanks Olek.

Comment: "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(688,5)`" In Delphi 11.3, that's referring to macOS deployment, so it makes sense that it refers to "`Distribution certificate has not been specified..`". Check which platform your automation script is actually building for.

Comment: set PLATFORM=iOSDevice64, @DaveNottage

Comment: Your script does not seem to refer to a `PLATFORM` variable in the `msbuild` statements

Comment: It should have `/p:platform=%PLATFORM%`

Comment: i´ve added your suggestion, and it just changed the line ... CodeGear.Deployment.targets(696,5) @DaveNottage

Comment: Please update your question, including the complete error message, and the changes to your script

Comment: @DaveNottage, done.

Comment: I've also remembered you need to specify a connection profile, so that it will connect to the Mac and find the provisioning profile (if you have one). The parameter is: `/p:Profile=%PROFILENAME%` e.g. if `PROFILENAME` is Mac, it will look for: `%APPDATA%\Embarcadero\BDS\22.0\Mac.profile`. If your build machine is not the same one as the development machine, you'll need to copy this file over

Comment: @DaveNottage, thanks but still doen´t work. same message.

Comment: Do you actually have an App Store provisioning profile on the Mac?

Comment: @DaveNottage, yeap. if i just press CTRL+ALT+F9 inside ide, it works flawlessly